# XF read a stream from resources ios

Tags: ios, file, xamarin.forms, stream

I am using XF, I have a bin file in my assets in android, and I am using dependency service to read the file, in android part I have no problem but I want to have the same thing in iOS. Does anybody know how it should be done?
This is my code in android side:

```
class UpdateHardware : IUpdateHardware
{
    public Stream OpenFile()
    {
        AssetManager assets = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets;
        var asset = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open("TesterProg.bin");
        return asset;       
    }
}
```

and the code that I am using in PCL:

```
private Stream GetFile()
 {
    return DependencyService.Get<IUpdateHardware>().OpenFile();
 }
```

I want the same thing for iOS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use .NET Standard or shared code?

Comment: There are libraries for accessing the file system but most of them are outdated or no well-maintained

Comment: @Ali123 I am using .NET Standard. So if the libraries are outdated, what should I do then?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET Standard, you can easily use System.IO.File in your project and it will automatically do the task for all platforms such as creating files, deleting ,reading, copying,...
[System.IO.File Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.IO.File?view=netframework-4.7.2)

If you are not using .NET Standard, you will need to use Dependency service in each platform to do the operation specifically for Android and iOS. This is what plugins such as [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) was doing for you.